# Setting device for pytorch version 0.3.1.post2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torch

In newer versions of pytorch, you can set the device by using torch.device. I need to use torch version 0.3.1.post2 for some legacy code. How do I set the device for this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use the `set_device` function. But this is not encouraged. Please see the [reference](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/cuda.html?highlight=set_device#torch.cuda.set_device).

The suggested method is, you just set the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environmental variable. You can run your script as follows.

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=GPU_ID python script_name.py
```

In your program, you can just simply use `.cuda()` to use GPUs. (e.g., `model=model.cuda()`)